# Abu Dhabi: Transit time and US pre-clearance question

Tags: transit, jfk, etihad, pre-clearance, auh

My parents will be traveling to the US (JFK) from India (BLR) and I am planning to buy their tickets on Etihad. I have a few questions regarding the transit and the US pre-clearance:

1. The flights I am looking at right now are EY237 (BLR-AUH) and EY103 (AUH-JFK). It seems like the transit time is going to be about 2 hours and 30 minutes. Is this sufficient to go through the US pre-clearance?
2. Once the pre-clearance is done, will they need to go through any additional checks/anything at JFK?
3. Since they will only be transiting through AUH, is a visitor/any visa required? I checked one of the websites and it says that a visa is not required if the transit time is < 4 hours. Is that correct?

Anything else that we need to be aware of?

Edit:
Edited per suggestions below.

Comment: Updated this question and posted another one with a few additional questions over at: 

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51511/transit-through-abu-dhabi-on-etihad


/* not sure if I'm allowed to cross post the links for the two threads, but I think it might just help*/

Comment: The US CBP publishes [historical queue times for Abu Dhabi preclearance](http://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance/abu-dhabi-international-airport-preclearance-queue-times). Last week, the _longest_ reported queue time was 30 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes I do believe it is, now that the situation there has improved. You are advised to present yourself at US Customs and Immigration at least sixty minutes before departure of your onward service.
2. No, you will arrive as a domestic flight. (In principle US Customs and Immigration have the power to inspect you again, but usually they will not.)
3. Not for an airside connection.